# Understanding numbers in PE

Tags: portable-executable

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the above graphs I know there are `9` sections,but why in the 1st graph it shows `0900`?

How to read numbers in PE format?

Answer (score 5):

The number is little endian, so the least significant byte comes first. Reverse the bytes to get the value in the order usually used by people, i.e. 0x0009.

Comment: Is it the case for all PE files?

Comment: @COMer: A quick google reveals at least this: http://www.thehackerslibrary.com/?p=377 which would say that all data is indeed in little endian format.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Matti Virkkunen answered your question. If you have any more questions regarding the format I have included the link to the specification.

[**PE COFF Specification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463125)

> NumberOfSections  The number of
>   sections. This indicates the size of
>   the section table, which immediately
>   follows the headers.

-pg 12